# Missing context keys for HTML::Pipeline::EmojiFilter: :asset_root

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm with a Rails 5 application and adding [html_pipeline gem](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline) with the [EmojiFilter extension](https://github.com/github/gemoji) so that I can process the text sent by the users and filter the emojies.

I have the following:

```
def filtered_content
    pipeline = HTML::Pipeline.new [
     HTML::Pipeline::PlainTextInputFilter,
     HTML::Pipeline::MarkdownFilter,
     HTML::Pipeline::SanitizationFilter,
     HTML::Pipeline::AutolinkFilter,
     HTML::Pipeline::EmojiFilter
    ]
   pipeline.call(content)[:output].to_s
end
```

I followed the usual steps adding the gemoji gem so that I can use the EmojiFilter, but when I add it to the pipeline declaration and try to use the pipeline I get the error:

```
Missing context keys for HTML::Pipeline::EmojiFilter: :asset_root
```

I added this on my assets.rb initializer:

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << "emoji/**/*.png"
```

And also ran "rake emoji" but the error is still there.

Any ideas of I could solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I [got feedback](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/issues/262) from html_pipeline collaborators. Basically what needs to be done to solve this is to add the context variable asset_root to indicate where the images should be read from (a local folder, a CDN url, etc.)

So the modified code on my question should be modified like this:

```
def filtered_content
    pipeline = HTML::Pipeline.new [
      HTML::Pipeline::PlainTextInputFilter,
      HTML::Pipeline::MarkdownFilter,
      HTML::Pipeline::SanitizationFilter,
      HTML::Pipeline::AutolinkFilter,
      HTML::Pipeline::EmojiFilter
    ], { asset_root: "the url of your assets" } # <------
    # E.g. GitHub uses this: "https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode"
    pipeline.call(content)[:output].to_s
end
```